# margin on layout is different when the app is started

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm new to iOS, trying my first app being remade from Android.
As far as I understood -20 margin sticks to the edge of the superview.
But in my case there is a gap which I don't understand. 
Here's a pic :

[image]

Here you see on emulator to the right where question mark is. If I change margin to -48 it covers everything. But that's not right. Where could I do wrong and what possibly could be changed?
Again, I'm new to iOS, don't know it's pecularities

Comment: I see a little yellow 20 there on the left side, are you receiving any warnings or errors related to your constraints? If everything is set up correctly, you would not see any yellow or red

Comment: @BJHStudios is that +28 on the left of Container? it's the left margin. it's not correct also

Comment: yes sorry, the 28...it's showing yellow as a warning that when the phone renders the view with the current constraints that side is expected to be +28 from where it is now. That probably accounts for that gap...I would suggest examining that constraint first

Comment: Is your "constrain to margins" checkbox ticked when you add constraints? If it is, uncheck it and try.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add this suggestion as a comment, but I can only add it as an answer (reputation too low).

I see that you have rootview.trailing.margin
Don't constrain it to rootviews margin, then you can just enter a constant of 0, and it should fit better

Answer (score 0):

The margin of 20 doesn't make your view stick to the edges of the superview, it makes it stick to the first blue line 20 points away from the edge of the super view. Please, make the margin 0 and you will see the gap dissapears.

hope this helps.